# Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement 5

Tags: mysqli, sql-update, bindparam

I am newbie in coding. i just create new members data for my travel agent, i am confusing when this code is not running well. when the first time i use this code for 4 rows in mysqli its running well, but when i tried for complex data, its not running.

here is mysqli code:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])):
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
      $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE jamaah SET berangkatbulan=?, berangkattahun=?,bulandaftar=?, tahundaftar=?, nomorktp=?, namapertama=?, 
                                                namakedua=?, namaketiga=?, namaayahkandung=?, tempattanggallahir=?, 
                                                umur=?, jeniskelamin=?, kewarganegaraan=?, alamatlengkap=?, rtrw=?, kelurahan=?, kecamatan=?, 
                                                kabupaten=?, provinsi=?, kodepos=?, nomortelepon=?,
                                                nomerhp=?, email=?, alamatjakarta=?, pendidikan=?, pekerjaan=?, pernahhaji=?, namamahram=?, hubunganmahram=?, 
                                                golongandarah=?, pilihpaket=? WHERE id=?");
      $stmt->bind_param('sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss', $berangkatbulan, $berangkattahun, $bulandaftar, $tahundaftar, $nomorktp, $namapertama,$namakedua, $namaketiga, $namaayahkandung,
                                $tempattanggallahir, $umur, $jeniskelamin, $kewarganegaraan, $alamatlengkap, $rtrw, $kelurahan, $kecamatan, $kabupaten,$provinsi,$kodepos,
                                $nomortelepon,$nomerhp,$email, $alamatjakarta,$pendidikan, $pekerjaan, $pernahhaji, $namamahram,$hubunganmahram, $golongandarah, $pilihpaket);

        $berangkatbulan=$_POST['berangkatbulan'];
        $berangkattahun=$_POST['berangkattahun'];
        $bulandaftar=$_POST['bulandaftar'];
        $tahundaftar=$_POST['tahundaftar'];
        $nomorktp=$_POST['nomorktp'];
        $namapertama=$_POST['namapertama'];
        $namakedua=$_POST['namakedua'];
        $namaketiga=$_POST['namaketiga'];
        $namaayahkandung=$_POST['namaayahkandung'];
        $tempattanggallahir=$_POST['tempattanggallahir'];
        $umur=$_POST['umur'];
        $jeniskelamin=$_POST['jeniskelamin'];
        $kewarganegaraan=$_POST['kewarganegaraan'];
        $alamatlengkap=$_POST['alamatlengkap'];
        $rtrw=$_POST['rtrw'];
        $kelurahan=$_POST['kelurahan'];
        $kecamatan=$_POST['kecamatan'];
        $kabupaten=$_POST['kabupaten'];
        $provinsi=$_POST['provinsi'];
        $kodepos=$_POST['kodepos'];
        $nomortelepon = $_POST['nomortelepon'];
        $nomerhp=$_POST['nomerhp'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $alamatjakarta=$_POST['alamatjakarta'];
        $pendidikan=$_POST['pendidikan'];
        $pekerjaan=$_POST['pekerjaan'];
        $pernahhaji=$_POST['pernahhaji'];
        $namamahram=$_POST['namamahram'];
        $hubunganmahram=$_POST['hubunganmahram'];
        $golongandarah=$_POST['golongandarah'];
        $pilihpaket=$_POST['pilihpaket'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];

      if($stmt->execute()):
           echo "<script>location.href='index.php'</script>";
      else:
           echo "<script>alert('".$stmt->error."')</script>";
      endif;
 endif;
 $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM jamaah WHERE id=".$_GET['id']);
 $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

when i click an update mysqli message is :

```
**Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in D:\xampp\htdocs\datarematour\admin\update.php on line 11**
```

and this is my sample php codes:

```
<label for="kewarganegaraan">Kewarganegaraan</label>
                            <select name="kewarganegaraan" class="form-control">
                            <option>-Pilih--</option>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['kewarganegaraan'] ?>">Warga Negara Indonesia</option>
                            <option>Warga Negara Asing</option>
                            </select>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 form-group">
                            <label for="namapertama">Nama Pertama</label>
                            <input type="text" name="namapertama" value="<?php echo $row['namapertama'] ?>" class="form-control">
                        </div>
```

Comment: You're missing the `id` bind.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Your query itself contains 32 question marks where your bind parameter fills the first 31 parameters but not the last one, the id

you have to add an `i` to the string variable of bind_param and then the variable containing the id value behind all the other variables